# Signup, Edit personal and Modify password forms in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc

Spring MVC, Signup, Edit personal and Password forms

My Spring MVC application is a website where members can subscribe to indoor and outdoor activities, organized by a member. THe application therefore needs a well-known funcionality to sign up, login and edit/modify personal details.
I used Spring MVC in combination with Thymeleaf views. THis works fine but I am struggling with the different forms and try to avoid redundant fields.

The following use cases are required:

Sign up: 
User chooses a username, password en password confirmation and personal details like birth date, gender, city, personal interests. 
After submitting the form, form validation checks whether username is not in use and passwords fields are equal.

Edit personal data:
When logged in, the user can choose to edit his/her personal data. Username cannot be changed (and is therefore invisible or at least immutable in this form) and password fields are not shown.

Edit password;
To change the password, the logged in user enters his existing password for extra security, and the new password and the confirmation of the new password. After committing, the existing password is verified and changed afterwards if and only of the new password and confirmation are matching.

I think this is pretty common functionality. But my issue is that we have only one Member class that can act as the form-backing object (The Spring MVC documentation advises against the use of separate form backing objects).
Besides, the password is not stored as the plain entered text, but as the (SHA-256) hash.

For the signup use case, I choose the following approach:
THe Member entity object contains one mapped field for the hashed password (which is persisted in the database) and two transient fields for entering the password which are bound to the form and validated for being equal and match other criteria (minimum length, special characters etc):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="member")
public class Member {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Size(min=3, max=25)
@Column(name = "loginname", nullable = false, updatable = false)
@NotEmpty
private String loginName;

@Transient
private String registerPassword;

@Transient
private String retypeRegisterPassword;

@Column(name = "password_sha256", nullable = false, updatable = false)
@NotEmpty
private String passwordHash;
```

... more fields, getters and setters

In the intitial signup form, the new user enters his username, password (Twice) and all other required fields. This works as expected.

But what if the user wants to edit his personal data? 
We do not want to edit the username and password fields in this scenario. The other fields need to be validated according to the same rules as the signup form. So we should need:
1) A separate form backing object, mimicking the Member object but without username and password fields. This sounds unacceptable to me due to redundancy.
2) Or use the same form backing object but somehow bypassing the username and password fields in the validation. Of course, those fields must be preserved when saving the member object back to the database using Hibernate, but we can make a customized update method in the service layer to handle that.

And the last use case is modifying the password. For this I want a separate form with 3 fields, the original password for extra verification and two fields for the new password  and its confirmation. 
I think I should use a separate form backing object for this containing only those 3 fields, but do not want to duplicate the field and validation definitions.

Is there a clean way to do this without redundant definitions?
Hope for some thoughts... :)

Comment: There is often a mismatch between what you show/need and what you have in your entity beans. I would consider the 2 additional transient fields already as leaking detail of your registration into your entities. I would try to keep the entities as clean as possible, create separate objects for the forms and have specific service methods to handle those objects. The web layer is now merely a thin conversion layer and you have specific easy to test methods that expose business functionality. For me this is pretty clean and easy to understand. Keeps all your objects nice and clean.

Comment: Thanx 4 your answer, so that would mean to use separate form objects. Though it is against the advice of Spring, it is maybe something to consider.  But the forms for signing up a new member or editing logged in member personal data would still be greatly similar and I look for a way to remove redundant definitions ad all costs... :)

Comment: To use a quote *"duplication is far cheaper, then the wrong abstraction"*. There is no advice in spring that says to do so, spring doesn't interfere with your architecture. The fact that things **look** similar doesn't mean they are. Signup I can imagine the need for a username, password, validation password etc. I can imagine those aren't needed when editing and that there is a separate form for changing the password (or requesting a new one). All separate use-cases with separated needs and properties. Added bonus your architecture now reflects the real life instead of that it is hidden.

Comment: OK this sounds pretty logical to me. I will go for the solution of some separate, dedicated form objects and keep the Hibernate entity class clean. I was thinking the other way around due to the advice of Spring MVC documentation: "Reusable business code, no need for duplication. Use existing business objects as command or form objects instead of mirroring them to extend a particular framework base class."  But it appears that there are many opinions contradicting this advice and is a subject of some years-old discussions...

Comment: For simple crud this could be done but if you surpass that stage it gets difficult and you will end up polluting your entities with use case specific fields which aren't in the database and only complicate your entity. But there is never a silver bullet or golden hammer what might work for you might not work or others. Generally architecture is highly opinionated.

Comment: Off-topic, but if you are going to store passwords in your database, please take a look at https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm.

Comment: Interesting article about the password but this is to be tackled later... I work on a solution using separated, dedicated DTO objects acting as form-backing objects. This is not really difficult except a mapping strategy must be used. Both when creating a DTO for the form, as copying it back to the entity object after a POST. Still reading about the options to make a good mapping while keeping the layers separated well.